# Suspend function inside flow kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So I have the below kotlin code with `flows` and `suspend` function.

```
suspend fun doWork(): Int {
    // do some time intensive task
    return if (task.isSuccessful){1}else{-1}
}

suspend fun sendTaskStatus(status:Int): Boolean {
    // send this status data to the server via internet 
    return task.isSuccessful()
}

fun listenForCompletion() = flow <String> {
    val isTaskCompleted = false
    val taskStatus = doWork()
    if (taskStaus == 1){
        val isDataSent = sendTaskStatus()
        if(isDataSent)
            isTaskCompleted = true
    }
    emit(isTaskCompleted)
}
```

Now my question is if I `collect` `listenForCompletion()` function from a `coroutine`, what will be the sequence of execution of this code? If this isn't correct what would be the correct way of doing this assuming that `flow` and `suspend` functions are preserved?

Comment: Your code contains a lot of errors, so it won't even compile, but let's ignore this for now. I'm not entirely sure what do you ask. Yes, this approach should do what you need and the execution order is what we would expect: we collect the flow, `doWork()` is executed, then `sendTaskStatus()`.

Comment: My concerns are: 1. Why use flow if we only return a single item? We can use suspend function here. 2. It doesn't matter if we invoke `listenForCompletion()` from coroutine or not. Invoking it itself does nothing, things start to happen when we collect the flow. 3. If `sendTaskStatus()` does IO and it is not suspend that means it has to be blocking. We shouldn't call blocking code from coroutines without using `Dispatchers.IO` or similar.

Comment: @broot to answer your questions:
1. As you can understand it is just part of the actual code, I have removed the boilerplate code that would lead to confusion.
2. Yes it is getting collected.
3. No it doesn't do any IO. Just sends the response to the server.